# jQuery - Dynamically add button over highcharts div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am dynamically creating a series of charts with `jQuery-3.2.1`, `highcharts` and `bootstrap-3`.

```
var iDiv = document.getElementById("logs");
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.id = key;
iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
$('#' + key).highcharts(json);
```

Now I am trying to add play and pause buttons over the chart `div` so that it looks like in the picture [image]

I am not an expert in jQuery and I am a bit confused about the several methods to do this. So far I have tried the following, but unsuccessfully.

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.addClass('btn btn-primary')
innerDiv.append(btn);
```

I have not added any style or event yet. The problem is that the button does not show up. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

First you can Create a button with some Default Styles, so that the Button Should Float over the Chart.

i am Creating Dynamic Buttons and Write the CSS for the Button so that it Looks Like it is on the Chart, Its Completely done with CSS and the Button creation is by using JavaScript[image].

you can't append any button inside chart.

Please Look into my image, I am created Two Dynamic buttons and provide necessary css so that it looks like it will be on the chart